# Lua Script : adding a repeating code for a mouse movement

Tags: lua, repeater

I'm currently looking over some Lua coding for a Logitech keyboard.

I can get the code to work on a single push,  I have placed a repeat and sleep timer and was hoping for this to continue to loop until I pushed the mouse button which is not woring.

This is what I have so far:

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 1  then
        PressMouseButton(3)
repeat
           MoveMouseRelative(-20,0)
            Sleep(50)
        until not PressMouseButton(1)
    end
end
```

Please note this is my first time looking over this type of coding as any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "which is not woring." is not very descriptive. You explained what you wanted your script to do, but not what the current incorrect behavior or error is.

Comment: Hi ktb, sorry about that, currently the program run and on press of the G1 key the screen moves with no repeat. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the G1 key to act as a toggle you are going to have to do things a little differently then you were doing. The only way to check to see if the G1 key is pressed is to respond to the click event using the `OnEvent()` handler. `IsMouseButtonPressed()` does not allow you to check the G keys.

If you are currently running the `OnEvent()` function after the keys is pressed, pressing the G1 key again will simply call the function again restarting the loop. To circumvent this issue you'll need to keep a flag that will prevent the function from re-entering the loop. Additionally, this flag will signal the original run of the `OnEvent()` to finish.

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 1  then
        if script_running then
            script_running = false
            return
        else
            script_running = true
        end
        PressMouseButton(3)
        repeat
            MoveMouseRelative(-20,0)
            Sleep(50)
        until not script_running
    end
end
```

The flag in the above example is `script_running`. On the first run of the function `script_running` is `nil` (which evaluates to `false`). So `script_running` is set to `true` and the loop is run. Then when you press the G1 key again it enters the function again, but this time `script_running` is `true`, which sets the `script_running` variable to `false` and exits the function. At that point the original loop will eventually meet the condition of the loop `not script_running == true` and will exit as well; stopping the script.

Yes, this is more involved than your original code, but unfortunately necessary.

Comment: Hi ktb, Thanks for looking over this for me. I will look at implementing the code. with this code the right mouse button is always pushed. Ideally i would like the following: Program to loop by pressing mouse right click hold move -20 and then release right click repeat 50ms delay. This coding is just the starting point for me to understand the Lua thinking.

Comment: Hi ktb I added the code to the script and it still is only doing it once on push of the G1 key with no repeat. The right click stay active just no movement of the mouse.

Comment: I am still not quite sure what behavior you want. After you press the G1 button, you want the loop to continue, which moves the mouse left, until you release the right button? Or until you release the G1 button?

Comment: Sorry i should of stated how i wanted it to work. i would like it to repeat until i push G1 again. Almost working as a toggle.

Comment: That is going to require a complete refactor of your code to work. I'll rewrite my answer and try to explain *why* you need the refactor.

Comment: Hi ktb, thanks for explain that and i understand what it is doing, on press of G1 key run scrip and them pres G1 again end script. at the same time its looking to see if the script is already running depending on its action. i have put this into the Logitech software and when i have the profile selected for this scrip it runs and repeats but when i press the G1 again its not doing anything. at the moment i have a work around by deactivating the profile which stops the script.